# bullet navigator not a

Tags: jssor, jquery-ui-slider, navigator

I'm adding a different-size-photo-slider to my site. The slider works properly but the bullet navigator does not appear.
I placed the bullet navigator inside 'slider1_container but it still doesn't work.
I imported the bullet png to the root folder too.
Thanks for your help.

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; width: 700px; height: 467px; background-color: #FFFFFF; overflow: hidden;">

        <!-- Loading Screen -->
<div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: absolute; display: block; background-color: #FFF; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(../img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
                top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Slides Container -->
        <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 1px; top: 5px; width: 700px; height: 467px; overflow: hidden;">
             <div>
                <a u=image href="#"><img src="images/MoscowSerie1/ moscou mockba 01.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
            <div>
                <a u=image href="#"><img src="images/MoscowSerie1/ moscou mockba 02.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a u=image href="#"><img src="images/MoscowSerie1/IMG_6130 copy.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a u=image href="#"><img src="images/MoscowSerie1/IMG_8611-Edit-Edit-1.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a u=image href="#"><img src="images/MoscowSerie1/IMG_6114 copy_2.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a u=image href="#"><img src="images/MoscowSerie1/IMG_5825 copy.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a u=image href="#"><img src="
            images/MoscowSerie1/IMG_2751 copy copy_1.jpg" /></a>
            <div>
                <a u=image href="#"><img src="images/MoscowSerie1/IMG_2209 copy.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a u=image href="#"><img src="images/MoscowSerie1/IMG_0518 _1.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a u=image href="#"><img src="images/MoscowSerie1/IMG_0390 copy.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a u=image href="#"><img src="images/MoscowSerie1/IMG_0380 bw copy.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a u=image href="#"><img src="images/MoscowSerie1/IMG_0341 bw copy copy.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a u=image href="#"><img src="images/MoscowSerie1/ moscou mockba 07.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a u=image href="#"><img src="images/MoscowSerie1/ moscou mockba 06.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a u=image href="#"><img src="images/MoscowSerie1/ moscou mockba 05.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a u=image href="#"><img src="images/MoscowSerie1/ moscou mockba 01.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a u=image href="#"><img src="images/MoscowSerie1/ moscou mockba 02.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a u=image href="#"><img src="images/MoscowSerie1/ moscou mockba 03.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a u=image href="#"><img src="images/MoscowSerie1/ moscou mockba 04.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--#region Bullet Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <!-- Help: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-bullet-navigator-jquery.html -->
        <style>
            /* jssor slider bullet navigator skin 13 css */
            /*
            .jssorb13 div           (normal)
            .jssorb13 div:hover     (normal mouseover)
            .jssorb13 .av           (active)
            .jssorb13 .av:hover     (active mouseover)
            .jssorb13 .dn           (mousedown)
            */
            .jssorb13 {
                position: absolute;
            }
            .jssorb13 div, .jssorb13 div:hover, .jssorb13 .av {
                position: absolute;
                /* size of bullet elment */
                width: 21px;
                height: 21px;
                background: <img src="images/SliderNavigators/b13.png" width="120" height="30" alt="navigator">;
                overflow: hidden;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .jssorb13 div { background-position: -5px -5px; }
            .jssorb13 div:hover, .jssorb13 .av:hover { background-position: -35px -5px; }
            .jssorb13 .av { background-position: -65px -5px; }
            .jssorb13 .dn, .jssorb13 .dn:hover { background-position: -95px -5px; }
        </style> 
        <!-- bullet navigator container -->
        <div u="navigator" class="jssorb13" style="position: absolute; bottom: 16px; right: 6px;">
        <!-- bullet navigator item prototype -->
        <div u="prototype" style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 21px; HEIGHT: 21px;"></div>
    </div>       
 <!--#endregion Bullet Navigator Skin End -->
        <a style="display: none" href="http://www.jssor.com">Thumbnail Slider</a>       
    </div>
    <!-- Jssor Slider End -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you specified `$BulletNavigatorOptions`

```
var options = {
   ...,

   BulletNavigatorOptions: {
        $JssorBulletNavigator$,
        $ChanceToShow: 2,
        $AutoCenter: 1,
        $Steps: 1,
        $Lanes: 1,
        $SpacingX: 10,
        $SpacingY: 10,
        $Orientation: 1
    }
};
```

**Edit**

Please upload `b13.png` to your `[root]/images` folder.

And replace

```
background: <img src="images/SliderNavigators/b13.png" width="120" height="30" alt="navigator">;
```

with

```
background: url(/images/SliderNavigators/b13.png) no-repeat;
```

Comment: Yes, I specified them...same as yours, just below the $SlideshowOptions: {}.   dont know what to do!

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jssor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jssor.slider.js"></script>

Comment: here is the page http://www.pascalebazire.com/XXXXXXdifferent-size-photo-slider.source%20copy.html.

Comment: b13.png is in the img folder. I think the problem is link to Prototype and background...e.g i can make appear letters instead of the bullet if i write<div u="prototype"> POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 21px; HEIGHT: 21px;"></div>
   </div>         and i changed the background instruction to   .jssorb13 div, .jssorb13 div:hover, .jssorb13 .av {
                position: absolute;
                /* size of bullet elment */
                
                background:  url( <img src="images/b13.png" width="120" height="30" alt="navigator">) no-repeat;
  but it does not change result

Comment: To be clear: i still cant get the bullets to appear ...the example with the letter PO replacing the bullet was just a script accident while trying to fix my problem ! sorry for the awful presentation of comments, i dont know how to make it better.

Comment: I don't think b13.png is in the img folder. Please see http://www.pascalebazire.com/img/b13.png

Comment: I think it is file:///Users/pascalebazire/Documents/MINI%20PASCALE/Web%20Design/Bazire%20Official/images/

Comment: Upload to your server then.

Comment: it has been but no navigator bullet file:///Users/pascalebazire/Desktop/Screen%20Shot%202015-05-08%20at%2013.23.25%20copy

Comment: Please send me the url of your b13.png on your server.

Comment: ftp://ftp.pascalebazire.com/www/images/b13.png   thanks for your patience

Comment: Hello, the slider is working fine but I still get an error message on the page : i get 'jssor_slider1_starter is not defined 'and I get "GET <http://www.pascalebazire.com/img/loading.gif> 404 (Not Found)"
And second problem,if I change the number of images, update and upload the modification, the number of bullets displayed remains unchanged.

Comment: As you uploaded the file to your `images` folder, pleaser replace `img/loading.gif` with `images/loading.gif`.

Comment: Ashamed to ask but which file are you referring to? the bullet navigator is images/SliderNavigators/b14.png . And out of despair, i placed in the same folder, the simple-fade-slideshow.source.html but still errors Uncaught ReferenceError: jssor_slider1_starter is not defined(anonymous function) @ MoscowPeople.html:196
jquery-1.9.1.min.js:6 and GET http://www.pascalebazire.com/img/loading.gif 404 (Not Found)(anonymous function) @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:6b.Callbacks.c @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:6b.Callbacks.p.fireWith @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:6b.extend.ready @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:6H @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:6

Comment: The problem is that your code refers to invalid urls. Includes js files and image files. I can't help because you don't understand.

Comment: No problem..it works online now, errors are invisible to general viewers.Thanks for help